# Oracle XMLDB retrieve invalid XML

Tags: oracle, oracle-xml-db, oracle-xml-db-repository

I have invalid XML files(some tag is missing) in XML DB which are uploaded using FTP. When I try to retrieve these files using `RESOURCE_VIEW`, i get below error.

```
SELECT rv.res.getClobVal() FROM resource_view rv WHERE  rv.any_path = '/test/test.xml';
```

> ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19213: error occurred in XML
> processing at lines 1 LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 't'
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 138
> 31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
> *Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
> *Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

How to retrieve such content using SQL or PL/SQL so that it can be edited and saved?

Comment: Can you please show the declaration for RESOURCE_VIEW?

Comment: Declaration of RESOURCE_VIEW [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/repository-access-using-RESOURCE_VIEW-and-PATH_VIEW.html#GUID-7B998BF8-1450-4C70-8C64-D9303C405F50)